# Display html files with another file extension on Apache server

Tags: apache-2.4, html, asp, extension

One of our systems generates files with an .asp extension that actually only html. I need to display those files on an Apache httpd server, which doesn't like asp files. Is there a way to indicate to the server to display those files as HTML files?

Comment: If you haven't specified a handler or content type for .asp files, Apache should just send them as-is by default, so they should work fine as HTML files. What happens when you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your httpd.conf or .htaccess file.

> AddType text/html  .asp .aspx

sudo a2enmod mime
Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype

To list apache loaded modules use:

> apachectl -M